# Integrating C++ Catch unit test framework with CMake

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, cmake, catch-unit-test

I am developing my application using Visual Studio 2015.

I have 6 projects in the solution of which 5 are libraries and one is a executable.

The executable project contains my test files and I am using `Catch framework` for testing. So I will be having 5 `cpp`files in the executable project. How can I run each test one by one using `CMake`?

`add_test` function of `CMake` takes the executable name as command and runs all tests at once.  I need to run each test separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple `add_test` calls with the right command line parameters.

In catch you can run a specific test by adding the name to the binary.

```
tester <testName>
```

So you can add those as arguments for the `add_test` call:

```
add_test(NAME mytest1 COMMAND tester test1 <...> )
add_test(NAME mytest2 COMMAND tester test2 <...> )
...
```

Then you can execute one specific test with

```
ctest -R mytest1
```

This only runts `mytest1`. -R also takes a regex in case you want to run multiple tests.

Comment: Is this <testname> name of testcase or the particular cpp file?

Comment: @Jackzz yes. for more details see here: https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/command-line.md

Comment: It is not only a name but a "testspec". you see more detail about this in the catch documentation.